# Is there a name for an 'incomplete' factorial $\frac{n!}{m!}$?

Tags: terminology, factorial

I noticed I was computing

> $${n! \over m!} ,$$

where $n > m$, inefficiently, as 
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n} k}{\prod_{k=1}^m k},$$
when many terms cancel out and I could just be calculating
$$\prod_{k=m+1}^n k .$$

Before I give this function a name, is there already a name or notation for it?  "Partial factorial"? "Incomplete factorial"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can write a ratio of factorials as the *[falling factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html)* or *descending factorial* or *lower factorial*. We can write it using the notation
$$x^{\underline k} := x (x - 1) \cdots (x - k + 1)$$
(the *[Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)* notation $(x)_k$ is also common): By cancellation we have
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\frac{n!}{m!} = n^{\,\underline {n - m}}}},$$
but of course $x^{\underline k}$ is perfectly defined for noninteger arguments $x$ too.
Anyway, the factorial notation here is surely much more familiar, and one probably couldn't use either of the other notations without comment. (Alternatively, we can write the above ratio as a *rising factorial* using the analogous notation $\color{#bf0000}{\smash{(m + 1)^{\overline {n - m}}}}$ or the Pochhammer notation $\color{#bf0000}{(m + 1)^{(n - m)}}$; the latter has the potential to be confusing for obvious reasons.)

Comment: I would add the symbols $x^{\underline n}$ and $x^{\overline n}$ for the falling and rising factorials, respectively; they’re increasingly common and have the advantage of not being lumbered with so many other possible meanings. I consider them a much better choice.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for pointing this out---I was unaware of the notation but I already much prefer it for reasons of semiotic distance from other notations alone. I've modified my answer to use it.

Comment: @Travis: You’re welcome. (And +1.)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The paper *[Two notes on notation](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211)* by D. Knuth provides a sound reasoning about notational aspects of *Iverson brackets* and *Stirling numbers*.

> D. Knuth also discusses factorial powers. He introduces in (2.11) and (2.12)
>
> - $z$ to the $n$ falling: $z^{\underline{n}}=z(z-1)\cdots (z-n+1)$ and
> - $z$ to the $n$ rising: $z^{\overline{n}}=z(z+1)\cdots (z+n-1)$

Comment: that's described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Alternate_notations

Comment: @endolith: Thanks for the hint!